# drawText функция печатает в обратном порядке Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt

```
   QPainter painter(this);

   painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3, Qt::SolidLine));
   painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);

   QRectF size = QRectF(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());
   painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::red, Qt::DiagCrossPattern));

   painter.translate(this->rect().bottomLeft());
   painter.scale(zoomX, zoomY);

   painter.drawRect(size);

   painter.drawText(QPoint(100, 100), QString::number(123));
```

печатает цифру в обратно порядке как исправить ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее вы направление оси y перепутали.

Comment: Может быть в `painter.scale(zoomX, zoomY);` `zoomY` отрицательный?

Comment: Да отрицательный

Comment: спасибо дал хорошую подсказку вот исправил

Comment: painter.scale(1, -1);
 painter.drawText(QPointF(i - 8, 40), QString::number(j));
 painter.scale(zoomX, zoomY);

Answer (score 0):

```
    painter.scale(1, -1);
    painter.drawText(QPointF(100, 100), QString::number(123));
    painter.scale(zoomX, zoomY);
```